# SOAPUI not generating the sample request while creating new project with WSDL

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, soapui

I am creating a new project in SOAPUI by WSDL and it creates my project successfully but when i click on the request i am not getting the sample request.

When i tried on another pc soapUI with same WSDL it is generating the sample request there.

Is there any configuration in SOAPUI which i am missing.

Comment: Check the soapUI logs (the tabs along the bottom of the application). Do they give any more information?

Comment: @craigcaulfield nothing related to request

Comment: So what are you getting ? can you share a screenshot. Hope you have selected the correct tab where the request appears

Comment: I am creating a new SOAP project with sample requests ticked. However, when the project is created there is no sample requests. It started happening after I ticked the second checkbox in screen shot "Create TestSuite"